How to remove "http://", "https://", or "www." from string in pandas
New to Python/pandas.
Within a column called "URL", I am trying to replace any URLs that have "http://", "https://", or "www." and just keep everything after it.
For example,
http://www.jhu.edu
http://www.brown.edu
http://https://www.amherst.edu
http://www.usc.edu

Should look like:
jhu.edu
brown.edu
amherst.edu
usc.edu


Please [edit] your question to include an [mre]. See [ask] for more information. Including what you've tried will make it easier to assist you.

@importrandom apologies. Just edited. Let me know if it's still not clear.

Isn’t this a trivial string replacement? What have you tried for yourself, and what problem are you facing?

Consider adding some sample setup code to your question. Check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples for reference.

# example
import pandas as pd
data = {'colA': ['http://www.jhu.edu', 'http://www.brown.edu', 'http://https://www.amherst.edu', 'http://www.usc.edu']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

use str.replace with regex
out = df['colA'].str.replace(r'https?://|www\.', '', regex=True)


In general, one can use .replace() to replace or remove (i.e., replace with the empty string) targeted strings in python. But maybe one should be more careful when reformatting urls, as a url might end in someTextwww.org or arbitraryTextwww.com etc. That is, a reckless .replace() method would only be appropriate if you already know it is safe to simply remove every instance of a substring, like "www." for example.
Here are two functions that accomplish the reformatting you are after. The first one string_formatter does the more reckless .replace() method, whereas the second is more careful (and should solve your problem in general), removing only the target strings that appear as prefixes.
# Here are the functions:
def string_formatter(stringList_to_format,subStrings_to_remove):
    newStringList=stringList_to_format
    for j in subStrings_to_remove:
        newStringList = [k.replace(j, '') for k in newStringList]
    return newStringList

def careful_url_formatter(stringList_to_format,prefix_strings_to_remove):
    newStringList=stringList_to_format
    loopSwitch=False
    while loopSwitch==False:
        checkList=newStringList
        for j in prefix_strings_to_remove:
            newStringList = [k[len(j):] if k[0:len(j)]==j else k for k in newStringList]
        loopSwitch=checkList==newStringList
    return newStringList

# Here is how to apply them to your URL formatting problem:

# collect your URLs in a list
original_url_list =["http://harvard.edu", "http://https://www.harvard.edu","https://stackoverflow.com","www.https://aTougherExampleEndingInwww.org"]

# collect the substrings to remove in a list:
substringsToRemove=['http://','www.','https://']

# Apply the correct reformatting function. Here, the example urls show how the first reformatting function might screw up, while the second is fine:
new_url_list_wrong=string_formatter(original_url_list,substringsToRemove)
new_url_list_correct=careful_url_formatter(original_url_list,substringsToRemove)
print(new_url_list_wrong,new_url_list_correct)

Notice the careful_url_formatter has a while loop, which is applied to handle cases where you have to remove several of the prefixes in sequence, as appeared in your example.
